# UIWebView won't store username and password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, keychain

I have an app where the user is redirected to a webview to sign in using oauth(twitter,google,facebook,etc).  The problem is that while using a uiwebview, the user must enter the username/password EVERY time.  This gets very annoying.  Is there a way to save the username/password in the fields?

I don't want to store the info in nsuserdefaults because I am told it is not secure.  Does the uiwebview have access to the keychain? and if so how do I get the uiwebview to get the username/password from the keychain and into the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

It's using the SA_OAuthTwitter Engine, and storing the auth-data in NSUserDefaults.
Without having used it myself, or even implemented Twitter in one of my applications, i think this is the way to go.

I really think you have to store the auth-data for the user, and use those data when making requests to Twitter.